# How can fetch data like a tree structure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

If I search `Pro` I need to get data like `Electronics > Mobile > Iphone > Pro`.

That means,

`Pro` `parent_id` is `3` `sibling_order` `3` is `Iphone`.

`Iphone` `parent_id` is `2` `sibling_order` `2` is `Mobile`.

`Mobile` `parent_id` is `1` `sibling_order` `1` is `Electronics`.

Another example:

If I search `Mobile` then I need to get data like `Electronics/Mobile`.

I tried recursive query but it is not working `Syntax error`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE category_path (id, name, path) AS
(
  SELECT id, name, name as path
    FROM categories
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.name, CONCAT(cp.path, ' > ', c.name)
    FROM category_path AS cp JOIN categories AS c
      ON cp.id = c.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM category_path
ORDER BY path;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
id  name              sibling_order  parent_id

1   Electronics             1         NULL
2   Mobile                  2          1
3   Iphone                  3          2
4   Pro                     4          3
5   SE                      5          3
6   XR                      6          3
7   Samsung                 7          2
8   Galaxy                  8          8
9   Note                    9          8
10  Home & Furniture        10        NULL
11  Kitchen Storage         11        11
12  Lunch Box               12        12
13  Living Room Furniture   13        11
14  Sofa                    14        13
```

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: What does `SELECT @@version;` report? If it's less than MySQL 8.0, then recursive queries aren't supported.

Comment: You might like my answer to [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree) or my presentation [Recursive Query Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/recursive-query-throwdown).

Comment: Hierarchical data can be done with [CTE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-recursive-cte/) - see reportsTo example.

Comment: @BillKarwin Mysql Server version: 5.7.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating a function that calls a recursive procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spCategoryPath`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `spCategoryPath`(IN `categoryID` INT UNSIGNED, OUT `return_path` TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE categoryName VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE categoryParentId INT;
    DECLARE pathResult TEXT;
    SET max_sp_recursion_depth=50;

    SELECT name, parent_id INTO categoryName, categoryParentId FROM categories WHERE id=categoryID;

    IF ISNULL(categoryParentId) THEN
        SELECT categoryName INTO return_path;
    ELSE
        CALL spCategoryPath(categoryParentId, pathResult);
        SELECT CONCAT(pathResult, ' > ', categoryName) INTO return_path;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;


DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `fnCategoryPath`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION fnCategoryPath(`categoryID` INT) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
       DECLARE pathResult TEXT;
       CALL spCategoryPath(categoryID, pathResult);
       RETURN pathResult;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The function is executed like this:

```
SELECT fnCategoryPath(6);
```

Generating the following result:
**Electronics > Mobile > Iphone > XR**